# How to have a navigation bar on every page Flutter Web

Tags: flutter-web

I'm trying to build a WebApp in Flutter, and need to have a navigation bar on every page. I am using a `MaterialApp` with defined `named routes`. I tried adding my navigation bar as part of the `body` of a `Scaffold` element within the `MaterialApp`, though it seemed to replace the named route widges. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:client/components/Shared/NavigationBar.dart';
import 'package:client/views/CreateWedding.dart';
import 'package:client/views/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Admin());
}

class Admin extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // home: Scaffold(
      //   body: Container(
      //     child: NavigationBar(),
      //   ),
      // ),
      initialRoute: Home.route,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        Home.route: (context) => Home(),
        CreateWedding.route: (context) => CreateWedding()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd use [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) but put it on top, and then heavily stylize it to belong there. Else, use packages if need to do it _fast_.
What kind of a navigation bar do you want? Do you have a sketch?

Comment: I'm not looking for anything too fancy, right now I'm more interested in the functionality over design, so just a row of links that will redirect to another view. This will probably eventually have close to 5-6 links.

Comment: Would it not be an anti-pattern (not sure if that's the appropriate word) for putting a `BottomNavigationBar` anywhere but at the bottom?

Comment: Would this work for you? https://blog.usejournal.com/interactive-navigation-items-in-flutter-web-7fccc5975779

Comment: If you just want some functionality right now, then go with `BottomNavigationBar`, it'll take under five minutes to get up and running. As far as it being an 'anti-pattern', upto your taste :)

Comment: Thanks for your responses, and sorry for the delayed reply. I saw the tutorial @BelleZaid posted, though coming from react, that seemed very complicated from what I expected, but I ended up just running with a modified version of that solution, and have been able to get it running. Thanks again!

Comment: For any one who needs an answer: https://dariadobszai.medium.com/interactive-navigation-items-in-flutter-web-7fccc5975779